# SAS Date and Datetime problems

Tags: sas

Q1:What does sas store for a date or a datetime data?Number of second from a fixed time point or something else?

Q2:Let's say I have two dates 07AUG2016 and 04MAY2015 stored in &date1 and &date2 how to get the difference of them in terms of number of day?
Should it be as simple as

`%let= &date2 - &date1`

what does it returns?
Many Thanks.

Comment: Let me google that for you. Wao, both answers on one page. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/68089/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions
SAS date value
is a value that represents the number of days between January 1, 1960, and a specified date. SAS can perform calculations on dates ranging from A.D. November 1582 to A.D. 19,900. Dates before January 1, 1960, are negative numbers; dates after January 1, 1960, are positive numbers.

[More details here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/68089/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm)